# $\rm Lux$ and $W/m^2$ relationship?

Tags: visible-light, units, power, metrology

I am reading a bit about solar energy, and for my own curiosity, I would really like to know the insolation on my balcony. That could tell me how much a solar panel could produce.

Now, I don't have any equipment, but I do have a smartphone, and an app called Light Meter, which tells me the *luminious flux per area* in the unit *lux*.

Can I in some way calculate W/m2 from lux? E.g. the current value of 6000lux.

Comment: lux are lumen/m². Lumen on the other hand are the power emitted in a steradian (i.e. a small portion of all possible directions your source could emit to) weighted by the [luminosity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function). The latter accounts for the variable sensitivity of the human eye to different wavelengths. So you'd have to 'de-weight' the lux in order to get the power/m².

Comment: If I might recommend a reference: the RCA E-O Handbook, a great compendium of definitions and formulas.  It is freely available per the descendent company of RCA.  One site is http://www.phy.davidson.edu/fachome/jny/optics/burle%20electro_optics.pdf

Comment: This article provides an indepth explantion on how to convert from one to the other: https://www.extrica.com/article/21667/pdf I think it is a good source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid that it is not easily possible to take the [luminous flux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminous_flux) and obtain the insolation (as [radiant flux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_flux)). Here's why:

The luminous flux $F$ is *calculated* from the radiant spectral power distribution $J(\lambda)$ by weighting each wavelength with a [luminosity function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function) $y(\lambda)$ as per

$$ F = c \int J(\lambda)y(\lambda)\mathrm{d}\lambda$$

where $c$ is some unit conversion constant between lumen and watts. The total radiant flux $\Phi$ would be

$$ \Phi = \int J(\lambda)\mathrm{d}\lambda $$

The problem is that the calculation of the luminous flux is not invertible - portions of $J(\lambda)$ lying outside the visible range are cut off by the luminosity function being zero there, and it is perfectly possible for two $J(\lambda)$ of different radiant flux $\Phi$ to have a similar luminous flux $F$.

However, in the case of solar radiation, there might be a way - we know the [spectral composition of sunlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight#Composition_and_power), and so we know the form of $J(\lambda)$ already quite well - you *could* try to run an algorithm that fits the scaling of the known spectrum $J(\lambda)$ to yield the value of $F$ you measure and then calculate $\Phi$ from that spectral function. I'm not sure how good this idea is though.

Comment: Your approach is, as they say, "close enough for jazz."  I wouldn't be surprised if solar panel mfrs or installers base their estimates on local luminous flux measurements plus a "simple" conversion formula.

Comment: I did an experiment measuring solar radiation with a pyranometer and a light meter that measured in lux. I implemented this algorithm using a black body distribution for the Sun with effective temperature 5780 K, and can confirm it does give results close to the W/m^2 pyranometer measurements!

Answer (score 16):

There is no simple conversion, it depends on the wavelength or color of the light.

However, for the sun there is an approximate conversion of $0.0079 \, \text{W/m}^2$ per Lux.

To plug in numbers as an example: if we read 75,000 Lux on a light sensor, we convert that reading to $\text{W/m}^2$ as follows:
$$75,000 \times 0.0079 = 590 \, \text{W/m}^2 \, .$$

[Source](http://bccp.berkeley.edu/o/Academy/workshop08/08%20PDFs/Inv_Square_Law.pdf)

Comment: This is a useful relationship and it would also be helpful to have information related to how the number of $0.0079W/m^2$ was derived.

Comment: +1 for the approximate conversion.

Comment: Citation no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Lux is a unit of "illuminance" and is based on the eye's response to light and each wavelength is weighted based on the percentage the eye is capable of perceiving.  The curve is loosely a bell curve so at deep purple the eye may only "see" 5% of the W/m2 available while in the fat green part of the visible curve it may "see" 90%.  So the ability to quantify lux, properly, means having a full spectral power distribution table of the incident light in W/m2/nm from about 390 to 810 nm, multiplying the value at each wavelength by the average human's eye response at that wavelength, and summing the results.

So lux as a measure of radiant energy only has value if you want to know how bright it will appear to a human, not any meaningful engineering measurement of spectral quality or heat energy.

Answer (score 1):

Lux is a unit that depends on the sensitivity of the "standard" (e.g. more or less average) human eye, as well as on the power distribution of light within the visible part of the spectrum. Your previous answers deal with that well enough.

The conversion from irradiance, or flux, in Watts per meter squared, to apparent magnitude is more simple, since these are both physical quantities independent of the spectral sensitivity of the human eye or of any detector.

m = −2.5 log F − 18.98224

where

m is apparent magnitude

F is flux in Wm⁻²

m,F pertain to the same spectral band

The derivation is fairly simple in the sense that it requires only algebra and a careful attention to the units of length involved (parsecs, meters).

Answer (score 0):

The luminous efficacy of radiation (LER) provides the way in which to convert from Watts to lumens or vice versa.  This ratio in lumens/watt provides the visibility index (under photopic conditions) of the light.  Green light at 555nm has a LER or 683 lm/W.  Any light short (bluer) or longer (redder) will reduce that figure.

Typical white light LEDs will have an LER of 250 - 350lm/W (this is not to be confused with the luminous efficacy that takes into account the electrical power used to create the light).  White LEDs are designed only to emit light that is visible so they optimise the LER.

LER is only concerned with the spectral properties of the light not the electrial properties.  The LER is the visible power divided by the radiant power of the light source.

Sunlight and other hot objects like tungsten filaments emit a lot of their light outside of the visible spectrum (in IR and UV) so the LER is much lower - e.g 50 lm/W.

So, to convert from Watts to lumens or vice versa the shape of the spectrum with energy (wavelength) needs to be known or assumptions made and then the LER can be calculated which will provide the conversion factor that is needed.